# DELETE statement in MySQL doesnt take the table name correct

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database called `broodjes-service`, whenever i run this query in it:

```
DELETE FROM order_items WHERE order_id = 42
```

I get this error:

```
#1146 Table 'broodjes-service.i' doesn't exist
```

While i'm sure this table exists, with this table structure:

[image]

**Problem**

I'm trying to delete a row from a table named `order_items`, but it takes the table name `i` for some reason.

**Questions**

- Why is it taking the table name `i`
- How can I make it so that my query will actually a row from that specific table?

---

I do have `triggers` for the table `order_items`

This one is for when deleting something:

[image]

```
UPDATE orders o
   INNER JOIN (SELECT i.order_id id, SUM(i.quantity * p.price) total_price
      FROM `orders-items` i 

   INNER JOIN products p ON p.id = i.products_id 
      AND i.order_id = old.order_id) t ON t.id = o.id 

SET o.total_price = t.total_price
```

**Insert trigger**

[image]

```
INNER JOIN (SELECT i.order_id id, SUM(i.quantity * p.price) total_price 
FROM `orders-items` i

INNER JOIN products p ON p.id = i.products_id AND i.order_id = new.order_id) t ON t.id = o.id 

SET o.total_price = t.total_price
```

**Update trigger**

[image]

```
UPDATE orders o INNER JOIN (SELECT i.order_id id, SUM(i.quantity * p.price) total_price FROM `orders-items` i INNER JOIN products p ON p.id = i.products_id AND i.order_id = new.order_id) t ON t.id = o.id SET o.total_price = t.total_price
```

Comment: Are there any triggers attached?

Comment: Try to update your delete trigger and use the table name there instead of the defined alias. Does the table "orders-items" exist?

Comment: Maybe test your delete trigger query separately ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM `broodjes-service`.order_items 
WHERE order_id = 42
```

If you use alias names then like this

```
DELETE i 
FROM `broodjes-service`.order_items i
WHERE order_id = 42
```

**Don't** mix db names and alias names

```
DELETE `broodjes-service`.i 
FROM `broodjes-service`.order_items i
WHERE order_id = 42
```

Comment: I updated my question, i do have triggers for it. One for delete, update and insert. Btw, when using your query i'm getting this error: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-service.order_items i WHERE order_id = 42' at line 1`

Comment: I corrected my answer. Your trigger code does not match your error. It must be somewhere else

Comment: Could it be because of the `-` in my DB name? or that the word `order` in `order_items` has already been reserved or something?

Comment: The error message in your comment is in fact from not escaping the DB name.

Comment: I'm going to try with the `_` character, because this is a part of my php code, where the IDE gives an error message on typing the ` ` `'s

Comment: This did'nt work, it stills throwing this error:  `Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'broodjes_service.i' doesn't exist` On this query: `DELETE FROM `broodjes_service`.order_items WHERE order_id = 42`

Comment: Obviously the error comes from another query since `broodjes_service.i` is not part of your delete query. Must be a trigger or event...

Comment: http://puu.sh/bmqPo/62339e4dbb.png apperently it does, i have no idea why.. Are you sure it doenst come from the trigger?

Comment: I think it is from a trigger, but not the one you added to your question. Look for code that contains `broodjes_service.i`

Comment: added all my triggers into my question.. cant seem to find it.

Comment: Your insert trigger is incomplete. Can you add that.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
Use broodjes-service;
DELETE FROM order_items WHERE order_id = 42
```